# PostgreSQL: how do I set the search_path from inside a function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to set the search_path before a query. The new search path should be based on a function parameter. How exactly can I Do it? Right now I have:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_sections(integer) RETURNS 
table(id integer, name varchar, type varchar) as $$
    SET search_path to $1, public;
    select id, name, type from sections;
$$ language 'sql';
```

But it simply won't accept $1. I also tried with quote_ident($1) but it did not work.

Thanks!

Comment: You need...Or do you? It would be good if you'd say why you need to do it that way instead of, say, just selecting in the normal schema.table way.

Comment: Jakub I'm developing a SaaS system where each client gets their own schema. The requests are made from node.js and node-postgres. Since a random request can be for one of multiple schemas, I need to set the schema before each query.

Comment: I forgot to add, I would really like to avoid concatenating schema and table names. If there was a way to avoid that, it would be great.

Comment: You could use a PL/pgSQL function and run the `set search_path` as dynamic SQL. Btw: the language name is an identifier and should not be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the language name is an identifier, so no single quotes. It should be `language sql` not `language 'sql'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Generic'ish solution

I created a pure sql function by using set_config().

This solution supports setting multiple schemas in a comma separated string. By default 
the change applies to the current session. Setting the "is_local" parameter to true makes the change only apply to the current transaction, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-admin.html for more details.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.set_search_path(path TEXT, is_local BOOLEAN DEFAULT false) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
    SELECT set_config('search_path', regexp_replace(path, '[^\w ,]', '', 'g'), is_local);
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Since we're not running any dynamic sql there should be less chance of sql injection. Just to be sure I added some naive sanitizing of the text by removing all characters except alphanumerics,space and comma. Escaping/quoting the string was not trivial, but I'm not an expert, so.. =)

Remember that there is no feedback if you set a malformed path.

Here is some sample code for testing:

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS testschema CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA testschema;
CREATE TABLE testschema.mytable ( id INTEGER );

SELECT set_search_path('testschema, public');
SHOW search_path;

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(123);
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

## A test based on OP's original code

Since we don't know the schema for mytable in advance, we need to use dynamic sql. I embedded the set_config-oneliner into the get_sections()-function instead of using the generic'ish function.

**Note:** I had to set is_local=false in set_config() for this to work. That means the modified path remains after the function is run. I'm not sure why.

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS testschema CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA testschema;
SET search_path TO public;

CREATE TABLE testschema.mytable ( id INTEGER, name varchar, type varchar );
INSERT INTO testschema.mytable VALUES (123,'name', 'some-type');
INSERT INTO testschema.mytable VALUES (567,'name2', 'beer');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_sections(schema_name TEXT) RETURNS 
TABLE(id integer, name varchar, type varchar) AS $$
BEGIN
    PERFORM set_config('search_path', regexp_replace(schema_name||', public', '[^\w ,]', '', 'g'), true);
    EXECUTE 'SELECT id, name, type FROM mytable';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SET search_path TO public;
SELECT * FROM get_sections('testschema');
SHOW search_path;  -- Unfortunately this has modified the search_path for the whole session.
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code will work

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_sections(num integer) RETURNS 
table(id integer, name varchar, type varchar) as $$
    EXECUTE FORMAT('SET search_path to %L::INTEGER, public;'num);
    select id, name, type from sections;
$$ language 'sql';
```