# Performance of Postgresql stored procedures/functions in a multi-tenant environment that has one db with many schemata (one for each tenant)

Tags: database, postgresql, function, multi-tenant, postgresql-performance

I am new to Postgresql and I am trying to figure out some details about stored procedures (which I think are actually called functions in pgsql) when used in a multiple schema environment.

The application I have in mind involves a multi-tenant DB design where one schema is used for each tenant and all schemata, which have the same table structure and names, are part of the same database. As far as I know from DBs in general, stored procedures/functions are pre-compiled and therefore faster so I woulid like to use them for performing operations on each schema's tables by sending the required parameters from the application server instead of sending a list of SQL commands. In addition, I would like to have a SINGLE set of functions that implement all the SELECT (including  JOIN type), INSERT, UPDATE, etc operations on the tables of each schema. This will allow to easily perform changes in each function and avoid SQL code replication and redundancy. As I found out, it is possible to create a set of functions in a schema `s0` and then create `s1, s2, ...` schemata (having all the same tables) that use these functions.

For exapmle, I can create a template schema named `s0` (identical to all others) and create a SQL or pl/pgSQL function that belongs to this schema and contains operations on the schema's tables. In this function, the table names are written without the schema prefix, i.e.
`first_table` and not `s0.first_table`

An example function could be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sel() RETURNS BIGINT 
AS 'SELECT count(a) from first_table;' 
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

As I have tested, this function works well. If I move to schema `s1` by entering:

```
set search_path to s1;
```

and then call the function again, the function acts upon `s1` schema's identically named table `first_table`.
The function could also include the parameter `path` in order to call it with a schema name and a command to change the `search_ path` similar to this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION doboth(path TEXT, is_local BOOLEAN DEFAULT false) RETURNS BIGINT AS $$
    SELECT set_config('search_path', regexp_replace(path, '[^\w ,]', '', 'g'), is_local);
    SELECT count(a) from first_table;
 $$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

as shown in the proposed solution in [PostgreSQL: how do I set the search_path from inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259551/postgresql-how-do-i-set-the-search-path-from-inside-a-function)

However, when I tried this and I called the function for a schema, I noticed that the second SELECT of the function was executed before the first, which led to executing the second SELECT on the wrong schema! This was really unexpected. Does anybody know the explanation to this behavior?

In order to bypass this issue, I created a plpgsql function that does the same thing and it worked without any execution order issues:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION doboth(path TEXT, is_local BOOLEAN DEFAULT false) RETURNS BIGINT AS $$ 
DECLARE result BIGINT;
BEGIN
PERFORM set_config('search_path', regexp_replace(path, '[^\w ,]', '', 'g'), is_local);
SELECT count(a) from first_table INTO result;
RETURN result;
END
 $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So, now some questions about performance this time:

1) Apart from a) having the selection of schema to operate and the specified operation on the schema in one transaction which is necessary for my multi-tenant implementation, and b) teaming together SQL commands and avoiding some extra data exchange between the application server and the DB server which is beneficial, do the Postgresql functions have any performance benefits over executing the same code in separate SQL commands?

2) In the described multi-tenant scenario with many schemata and one DB, 
does a function that is defined once and called for any identical schema to the one it is defined lose any of its performance benefits (if any)?

3) Is there any difference in performance between an SQL function and a PL/pgSQL function that contains the same operations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before I answer your questions, a remark to your SQL function.

It does not fail because the statements are executed in a wrong order, but because both queries are *parsed* before the first one is executed. The error message you get is somewhat like

```
ERROR:  relation "first_table" does not exist
[...]
CONTEXT:  SQL function "doboth" during startup
```

Note the “during startup”.

**Aswers**

1. You may experience a slight performance boost, particularly if the SQL statements are complicated, because the plans of SQL statements in a PL/pgSQL function are cached for the duration of a database session or until they are invalidated.

   If the plan for the query is cached by the PL/pgSQL function, but the SQL statement calling the function has to be planned every time, you might actually be worse of from a performance angle because of the overhead of executing the function.
2. Whenever you call the function with a different schema name, the query plan will be invalidated and has to be created anew. So if you change the schema name for every invocation, you won't gain anything.
3. SQL function don't cache query plans, so they don't perform better than the plain SQL query.

Note, however, that the gains from caching simple SQL statements in functions are not tremendous.

Use functions that just act as containers for SQL statements only if it makes life simpler for you, otherwise use plain SQL.

Do not only focus on performance uring design, but on a good architecture and a simple design.

If the same statements keep repeating over and over, you might gain more performance using prepared statements than using functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Actually, you are right, I do get the error you describe when I do `set search_path to public;` and then `SELECT s0.doboth('s1');`, but I still don't understand why, since `first_table` exists in both s0 and s1. If I do `set search_path to s0;` and then `SELECT s0.doboth('s1');` I get the count of `first_table` in s0 instead of s1.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I do not really believe there can be any issues with line execution order in functions. If you have any issues, it's your code not working, not Postgres.

Secondly, multi-tenant behavior is well implemented with `set search_path to s1, s0;`. There is usually no need for switching anything inside procedures.

Thirdly, there are no performance benefits in using stored procedures except for minimizing data flows between DB and the application. If you consider a query like `SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE somecolumn = $1` there is absolutely nothing you can optimize before you know the value of `$1`.

And finally, no, there is no significant difference between functions in SQL and PL/pgSQL. The most time is still consumed by reading through tables, so focus on perfecting that.

Hope that clarifies the situation. Also, you may want to consider security benefits of storage procedures. Just a hint.